# What does array.reduce(:lcm) mean in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays, reduce

I'm currently working on the fifth problem on Project Euler which has you find the smallest multiple that can be evenly divided by each number from 1 to 20. My solution worked but it took fairly long so I was looking at other solutions online. I found this code:

```
these = []
1.upto(20) {|i| these << i} # Easier than writing it out

puts "Answer: #{these.reduce(:lcm)}"
```

This code is way concise and it works in an instant as opposed to my code that took over two minutes to find the answer. My question is what does :1cm mean? I know you can pass :+ and other such options to reduce and they will add or multiply the elements of the array together, but I've never seen "1cm" before and my google fu is failing me.

Comment: You've cleared up your question about the method `lcm`. Do you understand, `reduce(:lcm)`?

Comment: @Styx_ You could replace your code by `p (1..20).reduce(:lcm)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lcm` is a method of `Integer` - check documentation [here](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.1.0/Integer.html#method-i-lcm)

> Returns the least common multiple (always positive). 0.lcm(x) and x.lcm(0) return zero.

```
2.lcm(2)                    #=> 2
3.lcm(-7)                   #=> 21
((1<<31)-1).lcm((1<<61)-1)  #=> 4951760154835678088235319297
```

Comment: Ahh, LCM not 1CM, got it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can also apply tis method directly to array and it will give lcm of all elements.

```
[1,2,3,4].reduce(:lcm)  # => 12 
[*1..20].reduce(:lcm) # => 232792560
```